# Conditional min and max flot chart

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to set my xaxis timespan depending on links that are clicked. I'm using the date.js library and if I put one date manually then it works. But I need conditional timespan for different dates. Here's the code for the options. I'm wondering if I could create a function and feed it to the xaxis in someway. I tried adding a function but it didn't work and would kill my plot.

```
 var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    <b>xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        minTickSize: [1, "month"],
        timeformat: "%m/%d",
        panRange: [Date.today().add(-2).years(),Date.today().add(3).years()],
        min: Date.today().add(-1).months(),
        max: Date.today().add(1).months()
        },</b>
    yaxis: {
        mode: "money",
        tickDecimals: 2,
        panRange: [0, 100],
        tickFormatter: dollarFormatter
    },
    zoom: {
        interactive: false

    },
    pan: {
        interactive: true
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    }
};
```

All I want to know basicly is it possible to create a function to modify min and max of the xaxis depending on timespan link clicked. For example when the 7d link is clicked I want a span of 7 days. When 1 month is clicked I want a timespan for a month in days. etc....
The bold is what I'm wanting to create a function that has a switch to change the min and max as well as the minTickSize depending on a link that's clicked to change the time span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to modify those values "on-the-fly" with flotjs. The only option is to store data into some variable and redraw chart with necessary parameters.